# how to get HWND for QDialog in Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'm trying to read the HWND of a dialog I sub-classed from QDialog, but I (think I) am running into a `Memory Access Error` which causes a null pointer to be returned to the client code.

Header file - I've given up trying to get an HWND as I can't even get a WId...

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsItem>

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

    WId getWindowHandle (void);
private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    QGraphicsTextItem *text;
};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

Implementation:

```
WId Dialog::getWindowHandle() {
    WId id = this->effectiveWinId(); // debugger says id = 0
    return id;
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
WId Dialog::getWindowHandle() {
    QWidget *parent = this->nativeParentWidget(); // debugger says parent = 0
    WId id = parent->effectiveWinId(); // so this crashes
    return id;
}
```

I'm new to Qt. Hopefully there's something obvious I'm missing.

What is the canonical way of getting a QDialog's WId?

Toolchain: Windows 10 Anniversary, Qt 5.7, both 64 bit, Visual Studio 14 C++ compiler, Windows SDK Debugger.

Comment: Try `this->window()->winId()`

Comment: **What do you need the HWND for?** Why do you assume that there is a HWND to start with? No modern UI will use native windows to build-up the interface. Qt doesn't do it, WPF doesn't do it, GTK doesn't, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps you.

Introduced in Qt 4.4, alien widgets are widgets unknown to the windowing system. They do not have a native window handle associated with them. This feature significantly speeds up widget painting, resizing, and removes flicker.

Should you require the old behavior with native windows, you can choose one of the following options:

1 Use the QT_USE_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1 in your environment.

2   Set the Qt::AA_NativeWindows attribute on your application. All
    widgets will be native widgets.

3   Set the Qt::WA_NativeWindow attribute on widgets: The widget itself
    and all of its ancestors will become native (unless
    Qt::WA_DontCreateNativeAncestors is set).

4   Call QWidget::winId to enforce a native window (this implies 3).

5  Set the Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen attribute to enforce a native window
    (this implies 3).

Refer QT documentation
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#effectiveWinId

Comment: 1. Don't. 2. Don't. 3. yes. 4. yes, but dangerous. 5. Not needed.

Comment: About 1, 2. Such approach will work, but it will cause to performance problems.

Comment: thanks Dmitry - your suggestion worked for me. this->window()->winId() returns a non-zero uint64.

Comment: The use of native windows in Qt is not extensively tested, it will make the performance abysmal, and is not really necessary. The asker hadn't yet convinced anyone that he actually needs the HWND. So far all we know is that he thinks he does need it.

Answer (score 0):

Dmitry's comment (above) has the works-for-me answer:

```
this->window()->winId()
```

returns a non-null uint64.

Thanks, Dmitry!